# Data cleanup with Regex in Pandas

Tags: python-3.x, regex, pandas, dataframe

I'm trying to use regex to extract two element fields.

From this list: df=pd.DataFrame({'Score':'Touch\n4.90\nDraw\n4.30\nDown\n1.58\nOver\n2.5\n**1.65**\nUnder\n2.5\n**2.23**']})

Desired result: `1.65\n2.23`

As showing I've partially attempted to remove some unwanted bits but getting lost with the other. What do I need to add to my regex solution to achieve my desired result.

```
import pandas as pd

df=pd.DataFrame({'Score': ['Touch\n4.90\nDraw\n4.30\nDown\n1.58\nOver\n2.5\n1.65\nUnder\n2.5\n2.23']})

df = df['Score'].str.replace(r'([^\d\.\n])', '').str.strip()

df
0    4.90\n\n4.30\n\n1.58\n\n2.5\n1.65\n\n2.5\n2.23
Name: Score, dtype: object
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```py
>>> df['Score'].str.findall(r'(?m)^(?:Over|Under)\n.*\n(.*)').str.join("\n")
0    1.65\n2.23
Name: Score, dtype: object
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/oHYW1T/1).

The regex matches all occurrences of second line below `Over` or `Under` line, and then joins the results with a newline.

**Details**

- `(?m)` - `re.M` inline option
- `^` - start of a line
- `(?:Over|Under)` - one of the two strings
- `\n.*\n` - a newline, any zero or more chars other than a line break char, as many as possible and then a newline
- `(.*)` - Group 1: any zero or more chars other than a line break char, as many as possible.

Comment: Great. Any simplified explanation for a newbie like me? Always appreciated :)